# Define incoming trigger event in Azure functions app terminology

Tags: azure, azure-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale says:

> Event driven. Scale out automatically, even during periods of high
> load. Azure Functions infrastructure scales CPU and memory resources
> by adding additional instances of the Functions host, based on the
> number of incoming trigger events.

Do activity functions being called by an orchestrator function count as an *"incoming trigger event"*?

Such as

```
yield context.df.callActivity('myActivity', {})
```

What about an orchestrator function being called by another type of trigger function, such as a queue trigger?

Such as:

```
const instanceId = await client.startNew('MyOrchestrator", undefined, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe YES to - activity functions being called by an orchestrator function count as an *"incoming trigger event"*. If we assume that the trigger is an event, then an orchestration instance will require an event in order to run the activity functions and invoke other orchestration functions.

> What about an orchestrator function being called by another type of trigger function, such as a queue trigger?

As mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#client-functions), we may call it as incoming trigger event because orchestration functions can be called using orchestrator client bindings (client function is the non-orchestrator function).